# A software for view MARC record file

Tags: windows-7, viewer

Is there any modern free software to view MARC record files in a human readable format?

Also a free MARC editor / convertor is useful.

I found [MarcEdit](http://people.oregonstate.edu/~reeset/marcedit/html/index.php), but I want a software that when is get a MARC file represent its content as a table or any others human readable format.

Comment: Yes, I presume there is – what have you already found and why didn't it work for you? Questions just asking for lists of software are considered off topic.

Comment: @slhck I found MarcEdit, but I want a software that when is get a MARC file represent its content as a table or any others human readable format.

Answer (score 1):

My preference would be marcdump from the Perl module MARC::Record.  You may not be happy installing Perl under Win7 though...